# Posición del cursor en un textarea

Tags: javascript, cursor

Estoy intentando hacer un pequeño editor de texto con los clásicos botones para poner el texto en negrita, cursiva, etc.

El campo para introducir el texto es un `textarea`, y he conseguido que se inserten las etiquetas Html correspondientes para esto, el problema es que las inserta al final *(uso `texto.value` para obtener el texto escrito y escribir las etiquetas)* y me gustaría que se insertara en el lugar donde está el cursor.

¿Alguien podría decirme como obtener la posición del cursor con Javascript, para que en base a eso pueda hacer esto que comento?

Comment: Te recomiendo investigar un poco y colocar el código y errore que tengas. He encontrado esta [respuesta _en inglés_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/263743/4092887).

Comment: Te puede servir esta respuesta http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/35670/6635 en el problema de fondo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es posible mediante está función ([referencia original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8549862/4987172)):

```js
var editor = $("#editor");

function getSelected()
{
  var u     = editor.val();
  var start = editor.get(0).selectionStart;
  var end   = editor.get(0).selectionEnd;

  return [u.substring(0, start), u.substring(end), u.substring(start, end)];
}

$("#negrita").click(function(){
  var select = getSelected();
 editor.html(select[0]+'<b>'+select[2]+'</b>'+select[1]);
});

$("#cursiva").click(function(){
  var select = getSelected();
  editor.val(select[0] + '<i>'+ select[2] + '</i>' + select[1]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="negrita">negrita</button>
<button id="cursiva">cursiva</button>
<br>
<textarea id="editor">texto de prueba</textarea>
```

Sin embargo el código html no se ve como tal en el textarea, por lo que puedes poner el reslutado de salida en un div (y emular el estilo de un textarea):

```js
var editor = $("#editor");
var output = $("#output");

function getSelected()
{
  var u     = editor.val();
  var start = editor.get(0).selectionStart;
  var end   = editor.get(0).selectionEnd;

  return [u.substring(0, start), u.substring(end), u.substring(start, end)];
}

$("#negrita").click(function(){
  var select = getSelected();
 editor.html(select[0]+'<b>'+select[2]+'</b>'+select[1]);
  output.html(select[0]+'<b>'+select[2]+'</b>'+select[1]);
});

$("#cursiva").click(function(){
  var select = getSelected();
  editor.val(select[0] + '<i>'+ select[2] + '</i>' + select[1]);
  output.html(select[0]+'<i>'+select[2]+'</i>'+select[1]);


});
```

```css
#output{
  background: white;
  width: 150px;
  height : 50px;
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;  
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="negrita">negrita</button>
<button id="cursiva">cursiva</button>
<br>
<textarea id="editor">texto de prueba</textarea>
<br>
<div contenteditable="true" id="output">texto de prueba</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

1-

```
    function  obtenerPosicionCursor(idElemento) {
  var campo = document.getElementById(idElemento);
       if (document.selection) {// Soporte IE
        campo.focus();                                        // Poner foco en elemento
        var oSel = document.selection.createRange();        // Para obtener posición del cursor 
        oSel.moveStart('character', -elemento.value.length);    //Mover cursor a posicion 0
        campo.selectionEnd = oSel.text.length;                    /
        oSel.setEndPoint('EndToStart', document.selection.createRange() );
        elemento.selectionStart = oSel.text.length;
      }
      return { start: elemento.selectionStart, end: elemento.selectionEnd };
    }
```

2-

```
    function posicionCursor()
{
       var tb = document.getElementById("miCuadrodeTexto")
        var cursor = -1;

        // IE
        if (document.selection && (document.selection != 'undefined'))
        {
            var _range = document.selection.createRange();
            var contador = 0;
            while (_range.move('character', -1))
                contador++;
            cursor = contador;
        }
       // FF
        else if (tb.selectionStart >= 0)
            cursor = tb.selectionStart;

       return cursor;
}
```

Fuente:

http://www.subgurim.net/Articulos/ajax-y-javascript/118/posicion-del-cursor-dentro-de-un-texto.aspx

http://isay-as.blogspot.com.co/2012/02/hola-todos-hoy-les-comparto-algo-que.html

slds

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo un enlace **no son bien recibidas**, y te pueden votar en negativo: ¿ Que pasa si los enlaces dejan de ser válidos ? ¿ No puedes mostrar un código de ejemplo, y desarrollar algo la respuesta ?